# No default link classes in typo3 8 anymore?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

In V7 all internal/external/download links got an additional class by default, like 'internal-link' or 'download'.

Looks like in V8 with the new CKEditor this feature is gone.

Is there a way to reimplement it via typoScript or some kind of yaml RTE config?

An automatic solution, not the solution where the user have to pick a custom style, thats our current workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If these classes should be applied automatically to specific link types without enabling the editors to change those classes, you should go for TypoScript `parseFunc`:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Parsefunc.html?highlight=parsefunc

Especially `makeLinks`, `tags` and `typolink` should be useful here:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Makelinks.html#makelinks
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Tags.html#tags
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Typolink.html#atagparams

For example you would assign a specific class to an external http link automatically created by makelink like this:

```
parseFunc {
    makelinks = 1
    makelinks {
        http {
            keep = path
            extTarget = _blank
            ATagParams = class="external-link"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this also work with internal file-links? For example to add a class="download" and target="_blank" to those via enhancing lib.parseFunc.tags.link and lib.parseFunc.tags.a.typolink?

Comment: Target should be working with this https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Typolink.html#filetarget

Not sure about the class though

Comment: Thanks. As a first attempt I just tried to change the target of internal links via
`lib.parseFunc_RTE.tags.a.typolink.target = _blank`
If I'm not completely wrong, this should work on links like 
`<a href="t3://page?uid=29">test</a>`
from bodytext of regular text content elements, but i does not. Maybe a bug?
I was wondering if lib.parseFunc_RTE.tags.a.typolink may not be executed for those, but
`lib.parseFunc_RTE.tags.a.typolink >`
removes the link like expected.

Comment: The next problem ist not all links use lib.parseFunc or lib.parseFunc_RTE, for example header-links:
`<f:link.typolink parameter="{link}">{header}</f:link.typolink>`
It could be difficult to implement that globally.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try.